# Spring MVC - inject map from yaml file

Tags: java, spring, yaml

I have a configuration YAML (application.yml) file which contains location data:

```
locations:
  countries:
    PL: Poland
    DE: Germany
    UK: UK
    RU: Russia
```

I would like to load it so it will be available in the html select field.

I have created a following class:

```
package eu.test.springdemo.model;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

import java.util.Map;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "locations")
public class CountryOptions {

    private Map<String, String> countries;

    public Map<String, String> getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }

    public void setCountries(Map<String, String> countries) {
        this.countries = countries;
    }
}
```

Then I inject CountryOptions to Controller by @Autowire. However the list of countries is empty in controller.

Configuration of app is provided by class containing following annotations:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CountryOptions.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages="eu.test.springdemo")
public class DemoAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
```

Controller code

```
package eu.test.springdemo.mvc;

import eu.test.springdemo.model.CountryOptions;
import eu.test.springdemo.model.Student;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    CountryOptions countryOptions;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showPage() {
        return "main-menu";
    }

    @GetMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("student", new Student());
        model.addAttribute("countries", countryOptions.getCountries());

        return "helloworld-form";
    }
}
```

So - any ideas why list of countries is not created from yaml file?

Comment: You didn't show your controller itself, and you didn't say whether you're actually using Spring Boot to run your application.

Comment: I do not use Spring Boot, just regular Spring MVC. Controller code is attached

Answer (score 1):

`@ConfigurationProperties` is a Spring Boot feature and will not be bound to the `application.yml` if you aren't using it. The best solution is usually to convert to Boot.

Comment: Ok. Is there any way to load the map from configuration file using annotations ?

Comment: @zleek Not just by piling extra annotations into the application without adopting Boot. The specific feature that you're wanting (property resolution from `application.yml`) is one of the bits most basic to Boot that if you include all the pieces necessary you're doing a full conversion anyway. Note that I've been using Spring since 3.0 and I have _exclusively_ used Boot for the last _seven years_.